# $q$-Pochhammer Function Not Evaluating Properly?

Tags: special-functions

I have recently (begrudgingly) had to make peace with the fact that the [$q$-Pochhammer symbol as encoded into *Mathematica*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html) has the product starting at index value 0 as opposed to 1.  So the command `QPochhammer[x, q]^(-1)` produces:

$$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-xq^{n}}.$$

If you want the product to start at $n=1$ like it must for many applications, you must manually multiply by $(1-x)$ in this example to cancel this term out.  I have a somewhat complicated product formula in which I carry out this procedure:

```
F[q_, y_, x_] := (x*(x + x^-1 - y - y^-1)*(1 - x^-1)^2)/
                 ((1-y*x)*(1 - (y^-1)*x)*(1-y*x^-1)*(1 - (x^-1)*(y^-1)))*
                 (QPochhammer[y*x, q]*QPochhammer[y*(x^(-1)), q]*
                 QPochhammer[(y^-1)*(x^(-1)), q]*QPochhammer[x*(y^(-1)), q])/
                 (QPochhammer[x, q]^2*QPochhammer[x^(-1), q]^2);
```

Written out this looks like: (just for presentability I've collected all the terms irrelevant for this question into "$\phi(x,y)$")

$$F(q,y,x) =\phi(x,y)(1-x^{-1})^{2} \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1-yxq^{n})(1-y^{-1}x^{-1}q^{n})(1-y^{-1}xq^{n})(1-yx^{-1}q^{n})}{(1-xq^{n})^{2}(1-x^{-1}q^{n})^{2}}.$$

Now, if in *Mathematica* you evaluate $F(q,y,1)$ you get *zero*.  This is presumably because of that factor out front of the product.  However this is clearly wrong!  Looking at the denominator of the product there should be a pole at $x=1$.  (What I call $\phi$ is neither zero nor singular at $x=1$.)

This seems to be happening only because I have to play this irritating game described above to account for the reindexing of the Pochhammer product.

**Question:** Is there a better way to implement Pochhammers starting with index value 1 instead of 0?  Or, is there a way to force *Mathematica* to correctly evaluate what I inputted correctly already?

Comment: Why not use `QPochhammer[x q, q]` instead of `QPochhammer[x, q]/(1-x)`?

Comment: @CarlWoll Ah thanks, that's probably the idea!  I'll try that but it seems like it should work.  Still strange that it evaluated improperly the other way.

Comment: Never mind, I was thinking of sums... deleting my comment.

Comment: So you're right, the result `0` is wrong and that's because for generic `q` and `y` the `QPochhammer` remain unevaluated even though there's a `QPochhammer[1, q]` that should be simplified...

Comment: @Jens Thanks for checking :)  Carl Woll's comment above worked perfectly for me.  It's also much cleaner to write that way.

Comment: Things boil down to the question: should *Mathematica* evaluate a product in which one factor is zero and the other is unevaluated? It does do that generically, but here it's not consistent with the value of `QPochhammer[1,q]` which is always `0`, which should be recognized. It's definitely a corner case because as soon as `x` isn't exactly 1 the function becomes undefined in certain ranges of `q`.